# Windows 10 - Multiple windows of the same program min/maximizing together and staying on top

Tags: windows-10, display, window

I recently switched to Windows 10 from Windows 7 and have run into this new windows 10 feature. I frequently work with a program that has several windows open at once (Blender.) I have multiple monitors, and I put one window on each monitor (note: this issue exists even with only a single display.)

If I minimize or maximize the primary Blender window, it minimizes/maximizes all of the other Blender windows. If I have a different program's window in front of one of the secondary Blender windows, and I click into any blender window, it moves all the Blender windows to be on top. This makes it impossible to keep other programs visible to view reference images, or text notes, while working in only one window.

I want to get back to the old behavior I had under Windows 7 where it treated these separate windows independently and didn't link their min/max or on bring them to front. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this.

Right click on the Task Bar and select Task Bar Properties.

Look down the right side and see: "Combine Task Bar Buttons".  Default is Always (that is what you see). Set to Never if that is what you want.

Thought for you: After 6 years of Windows 10, I Always Combine. Why?  Easier overall and hovering over the icon will allow you to pick out the correct one.

As I say - just a thought.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually already had it set on Never, and it did not help. But I realized that lower down, there was options for Multiple Displays with greyed out fields for when to combine. I had the Taskbar disabled on my other screens, so I assumed this didn't matter. I enabled it, changed the dropdown to Never, and disabled it. This has solved the problem.

Comment: Upon further investigation, this has only solved the problem of it maximizing/minimizing all windows when I select the primary window. It has NOT solved the problem of it bringing all to front when I select the primary window.

Comment: I tested here. I will look around for another monitor to try to replicate the issue.